# Order the record base on selected language

Tags: php, mysql

i have a sorting problem using PHP, mysql query here is tables structure

**User Table:**

userId,userName,email

**Languages Table:**

langId, langName

**user languages table:**

userId,langId

and i am using following query to get result

```
SELECT
users.* 
  COUNT(*)  AS languages
FROM userLanguages JOIN users ON users.userId=userLanguages.userId
WHERE langId IN(1,4) 
GROUP BY userId
ORDER BY languages
```

Now the problem is records are not get sorted according to languages searched

example:

in search : english,french
result should be sorted in following order

1.english and french

2.just english or just french

3.english and others , or french and other if any

i will be very thank full if any one helpe me to solve this issue 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that's your query? You've misspelled `userId` in your GROUP BY clause. You're also ordering by languages, which is the number of languages a user has, not what languages they have. Based on your specific sort order, you might want to look at a UNION, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks James yes it's my query it may misspelled because actual tables have many columns and i just modify it manually to make it understandable and about ordering by languages because no other solution providing me best match and you are right , can you give any idea or example how i manage this?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't do much with MySQL these days, but I could probably assist with a T-SQL answer that would be pretty darn close to the final solution. Can you tell us a bit more about your search? Does the user select one or more languages, and then the search results are returned based upon your above rules if more than one is selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to order alphabeticaly on langName

```
SELECT users.* COUNT(*) AS languages FROM userLanguages JOIN users ON users.userId=userLanguages.userId JOIN languages ON  languages.langID=userLanguages.langId WHERE langId IN(1,4) GROUP BY userId ORDER BY languages.langName
```

But if  you want an other order, maybe you will need to add a "order" column in langagues.table

( "order" is a reserved word in mysql, but you can name it "ordering" for example)